# Using Server 2008 as a router, DHCP, DNS, and AD

Tags: windows-server-2008

So I'm fairly new to Windows Server 2008 R2, and I'm looking to get my hands dirty and get a test box going on my home network by creating a domain. This is the first time I've done something like this from scratch, and I have a few questions that I need some sound advice on.

Before elaborating, here's my setup: internet -> dsl modem with static IP -> server 2008 (2 LAN ports) -> switch -> clients

So what I have done is setup Server 2008 with DNS, DHCP, and AD. I have an intermediate understanding of both of them, and was able to get the DHCP addresses transmitting. I ran into problems with DNS and internet access, and I think I've done something wrong as far as routing.

Do I set one of the LAN ports with the static IP and then a local IP on the other and a crossover cable to the switch? Do I need to setup routing in 2008? Are there any good resources for someone in my position? Thanks faulters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a switch, then I would have the dsl modem plugged into the switch and your server plugged into the switch instead of the path you have described.  The dhcp setup wizard should get you going pretty easily in that respect.  Try this configuration and see if one of your clients can pull and IP address from your server.

Also, I would have a router or firewall in between the modem and switch, if for no other reason to assign it a gateway address to it.  Then you can statically assign that information to your server to pull internet acces for it.

Comment: Ok, so if I have a dinky little netgear router, I can give it the static IP information and turn DHCP off, then connect it to the switch, correct? Then connect the server to the switch, broadcasting DHCP with the router as a gateway? I tried that and was still having problems. Are there any peculiar things I might need to check?

Comment: If you want the server to handle the DHCP, you'll have to turn off DHCP on the router.  If you have both devices attempting to perform the DHCP you can run into problems.  If the DHCP setup is correct, the clients should pull IP addresses from the server, including the gateway address, and be able to access the internet.  Follow through this guide: http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-server-2008/how-to-setup-dhcp-server-in-windows-server-2008-step-by-step-guide/ to double check the setup.

Comment: I've given you the answer because everything you're saying makes sense. I'll give it a shot! Thanks NB!

Comment: Thanks! I was in the same situation with win 2003 about 7 years ago trying to understand how to get it all working.